# Lie theory, history

Tags: lie-algebras, math-history

I am trying to understand how Sophus Lie's work relates to linear algebraic group's correspondence with a Lie algebra, anyone could help? I'm having some trouble going from differential geometry to algebraic geometry.

Comment: Are you interested in the math or the history? In the latter case, consider asking the question on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

Your question leaves room for many answers; any real algebraic group is also a real Lie group. Passing to its Lie algebra is perhaps going from "differential geometry to algebra". For more details on Lie groups, algebraic groups and Lie algebras see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832624/lie-groups-lie-algebras-to-algebraic-groups). Concerning "correspondence", I would think of Lie's three fundamental theorems. For example, consider

*Lie's Third Theorem*: Every finite-dimensional real Lie algebra $L$ is integrable, that is, there exists a Lie group $G$ with $Lie(G)\cong L$.

For a proof see, for example, the note by J. Ebert [Van Est's exposition of Cartan's proof of Lie's third theorem](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/talks/lieIII.pdf), and the references.

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Hawkins's [*Emergence of the Theory of Lie Groups: An Essay in the History of Mathematics 1869–1926*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#book_id=4507&panel=book_details) (2000) would answer your question.

Comment: Could you elaborate?